# Go to bash mode in a remote server(networking operating system) using python

Tags: python, ssh, network-programming, paramiko

I want to automate getting current kernel version using python.I tried to `ssh` to server(networking operating system) using `paramiko` then tried to execute below commands

```
OS10# system bash
admin@OS10:~$ uname -r
3.16.51
```

Below is my python script

```
import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko

host = '100.97.100.12'
i = 1


while True:
    print "Trying to connect to %s (%i/30)" % (host, i)

    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())     
        ssh.connect(hostname=host,port=22,username="admin",password="admin",
          timeout=float(10),allow_agent=False ,look_for_keys=False)
        print "Connected to %s" % host
        break
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print "Authentication failed when connecting to %s" % host
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print "Could not SSH to %s, waiting for it to start" % host
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)

    # If we could not connect within time limit
    if i == 30:
        print "Could not connect to %s. Giving up" % host

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("system bash")

ssh_output = stdout.read()
ssh_error = stderr.read()
print(ssh_output)
print(ssh_error)
ssh.close()
```

I am able to connect to host, but its not giving any `error` no `output` when executing the command .

Comment: Do you mean to execute `"system bash"`? Shouldn't that be `uname -r`?

Comment: Yes its `uname -r` only , but I am not able execute this command after sshing (because its switch server) , hence I have to go bash mode `system bash` , then execute the command

Comment: But you never call `uname -r` in the above? Does `/bin/bash -c 'uname -r'` work?

Comment: Also could be worth setting `bufsize=0` in `exec_command`

Comment: Actually `system bash` was not working so did't proceed , will try what you suggested

Comment: Tried what you have suggested but no luck >>`OS10# /bin/bash -c 'uname -r'`
`% Error: Unrecognized command.`

Answer (score 0):

Try executing:

`/path/to/bash -c 'uname -r'`

Where you can determine `path/to/bash` by SSHing to your server and looking at the path to bash on `cat /etc/shells` or `which bash`. Alternatively you could use [`chsh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) to change the default shell permanently.